# Python Threading vs Multiprocessing to improve REST API responsiveness "fire and forget" tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, optimization, multiprocessing

I am somewhat new to both threading and multiprocessing in Python, as well as dealing with the concept of the GIL. I have a situation where I have time consuming fire and forget tasks that I need the server to run, but the server should immediately reply to the client and basically be like "okay, your thing was submitted" so that the client does not hang waiting for the thing to complete. An example of what one of the "things" might do is pull down some data from a database or two, compare that data, and then write the result to another database. The databases are remote, not locally on the same host as the server itself. Another example, is crunching some data and then sending a text as a result of that. The client does not care about the data, but someone will receive a text later with some information that is the result of the data crunching from the various dictionaries and database entries. However, there could be many such requests pouring in from many clients. The goal here is to spawn a thread, or process that essentially kills itself because we don't care at all about returning any data from it.

At a glance, my understanding is that both multiprocessing and threading can achieve similar results for this use case. My main concerns are that I can immediately launch the function to go do its own thing and return to the client quickly so it does not hang. There are many, many requests coming in simultaneously from many, many clients in this scenario. As a result, my understanding is that multiprocessing may be better, so that these tasks would not need to be executed as sequential threads because of the GIL. However, I am unsure of how to make the processes end themselves when they are done with their task rather than needing to wait for them.

An example of the problem

```
@route('/api/example', methods=["POST"])
def example_request(self, request):
      request_data = request.get_json()
      crunch_data_and_send_text(request_data) # Takes maybe 5-10 seconds, doesn't return data
      return # Return to client. Would like to return to client immediately rather than waiting
```

Would threading or multiprocessing be better here? And how can I make the process (or thread) .join() itself effectively when it is done rather than needing to join it before I can return to the client.

I have also considered asyncio which I think would allow something that would also improve this, but the existing codebase I have inherited is so large that it is infeasible to rewrite in async for the time being, and library replacements may need to be found in that case, so it is not an option.

```
#Threading
from threading import Thread

@route('/api/example', methods=["POST"])
def example_request(self, request):
      request_data = request.get_json()
      fire_and_forget = Thread(target = crunch_data_and_send_text, args=(request_data,))
      fire_and_forget.start()
      return # Return to client. Would like to return to client immediately rather than waiting
```

```
# Multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
@route('/api/example', methods=["POST"])
def example_request(self, request):
      request_data = request.get_json()
      fire_and_forget = Process(target = crunch_data_and_send_text, args=(request_data,))
      fire_and_forget.start()
      return # Return to client. Would like to return to client immediately rather than waiting
```

Which of these is better for this use case? Is there a way I can have them .join() themselves automatically when they finish rather than needing to actually sit here in the function and wait for them to complete before returning to the client?

To be clear, asyncio is unfortunately NOT an option for me.

Comment: In addition to the option Elie Saad mentions, there are also other options for a message queue, which provide the ability to run background tasks, such as [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) and [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Advance Python Scheduler.

Instead of running your function in a thread, schedule it to run and immediately return to client.

After setting up your flask app, setup [Flask-APScheduler](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-APScheduler/) and then schedule your function to run in the background.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler({
    --- setup the scheduler ---
    })

@route('/api/example', methods=["POST"])
def example_request(self, request):
     request_data = request.get_json()
     job = scheduler.add_job(crunch_data_and_send_text, 'date', run_date=datetime.utcnow())
     return "The request is being processed ..."
```

to pass arguments to crunch_data_and_send_text you can do:

```
lambda: crunch_data_and_send_text(request_data)
```

here is the [User Guide](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html)